# Where is jar for java.io.File?

Tags: java, android, javap

When I need to get method signatures for `android.content.ContextWrapper`, I go to

"C:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-sdk\platforms\android-18" where android.jar is placed and then execute

`javap -s -classpath android.jar android.content.ContextWrapper > out.txt`

Now, I need to get method signatures for `java.io.File`. How is corresponding .jar named?

Comment: For android, `java.io.File` should be inside the same jar, `android.jar`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its present in the `rt.jar`. You can use the [JarFinder](http://www.jarfinder.com/) to find jars and classes.

Its present in the `lib` folder of jdk installation directory.

Answer (score 2):

This is `rt.jar` from your JRE or JDK, namely inside `lib` on the JRE. Given that you are using Windows, I would head to:

```
C:\program files\java\jdk1.7.0_25\jre\lib
```

for a JDK (changing the location to your JDK).

`android.jar` *also* has that file, but the former should suffice for a non-android implementation.

Answer (score 2):

As of Android SDK 16 (I haven't tested this in Android 18) `android.jar` also has the `java.io.File` class.

Try opening it as a ZIP file and see which files it has.

`ContentWrapper` is in the `android/content` folder.

`File` exists in the `java/io` folder.

Here are the first few lines of javap output for `android.jar` `java.io.File`

```
Compiled from "File.java"
public class java.io.File implements java.io.Serializable, java.lang.Comparable<java.io.File> {
  public static final char separatorChar;
    Signature: C
  public static final java.lang.String separator;
    Signature: Ljava/lang/String;
  public static final char pathSeparatorChar;
    Signature: C
  public static final java.lang.String pathSeparator;
    Signature: Ljava/lang/String;
  static final boolean $assertionsDisabled;
    Signature: Z
  int getPrefixLength();
    Signature: ()I

  public java.io.File(java.lang.String);
    Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;)V

  public java.io.File(java.lang.String, java.lang.String);
    Signature: (Ljava/lang/String;Ljava/lang/String;)V
```

Answer (score 1):

It is present in the `java runtime library` of java version you are using. For me it is in

```
/home/aniket/jdk1.7.0_11/jre/lib/rt.jar
```

Check accordingly.